# Does this linear representation of 112 roots of $E_8$ follow from the (extended) Hamming code's relation to the $E_8$ lattice?

Tags: algebraic-groups, root-systems

Background:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E8_lattice#Hamming_code

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E8_(mathematics)

Question:

Does the following linear representation of 112 roots of $E_8$ follow from the known relationship between the (extended) Hamming code and the $E_8$ lattice?

Naively and intuitively, I don't think so.  But naivete and intuition only work well during what C.S Peirce called the "abductive" phase of discovery, not afterwards.  So please take a look and see what you think.

Edited 12/27/2017 to add: Please see also this follow-up question, which gives the linearization of the remaining 128 roots of $E_8$:

[Is there an internally consistent nearest-neighbor relation in this complete linearization of the 240 roots of $E_8$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2578813/is-there-an-internally-consistent-nearest-neighbor-relation-in-this-complete-lin)

Linear representation of 112 roots of $E_8$:

Given any ordered string S of 9 letters over any alphabet A , S obviously contains only 8 ordered 2-tuples composed of adjacent letters, and therefore:

1) only 28 possible choices of UNordered pairs of such 2-tuples:

```
12,23

12,34  23,34

12,45  23,45  34,45

12,56  23,56  34,56  45,56

12,67  23,67  34,67  45,67  56,67

12,78  23,78  34,78  45,78  56,78  67,78

12,89  23,89  34,89  45,89  56,89  67,89  78,89
```

2) only 56 possible choices of ORDERED pairs of such 2-tuples, e.g. (23,12) as well as (12,23), etc.

Now suppose that we are allowed to read S "forward" or "backward".  Then corrsponding to (1) and (2), we will have:

3) only 28 possible choices of UNordered pairs of 2-tuples:

```
98,87

98,76  87,76

98,65  87,65  76,65

98,54  87,54  76,54  65,54

98,43  87,43  76,43  65,43  54,43

98,32  87,32  76,32  65,32  54,32  43,32

98,21  87,21  76,21  65,21  54,21  43,21  32,21
```

4) only 56 possible choices of ORDERED pairs of such 2-tuples, e.g. (87,98) as well as (98,87), etc.

Hence, we will have 112 ordered pairs of ordered 2-tuples, each unqiuely identified by:

5) an index R indicating which way we R(ead) a 9-tuple (backward or forward)

6) an index O indicating which way we chose to O(rder) each Unordered pair of 2-tuples (in its "natural" order relative to our initial choice of read-direction, or in its "reverse" order relative to our initial choice of read-direction.)

7) an index L indicating which of the 28 pairing L(ocations) we chose

And clearly:

8) the 112 resulting (R,O,L) triples can be mapped in an obvious way onto the 112 roots of $E_8$ which have integer entries when the roots of $E_8$ are coordinatized in the usual way:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E8_(mathematics)

For example

```
        Root              L         R          O
(+1,+1,0,0,0,0,0,0)    (12,23)   forward    natural
(+1,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0)    (23,12)   forward    reverse
(-1,+1,0,0,0,0,0,0)    (98,87)   backward   natural
(-1,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0)    (87,98)   backward   reverse
```

9) the 112 (R,O,L) triples can be paired off in an obvious way as inverses of one another.

Edited 12/27 to add: Please also see this related "bounty" question:

[Is there an internally consistent nearest-neighbor relation in this complete linearization of the 240 roots of $E_8$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2578813/is-there-an-internally-consistent-nearest-neighbor-relation-in-this-complete-lin)

Comment: David, I will try and shed some light to the connection between $E_8$ and the extended Hamming code as an answer to some of your questions. It just happened that my old laptop froze last Friday, so I could only buy a new one today. It is still a bit lacking in basic software like TeX and Mathematica, so I cannot promise a schedule. Anyway, looks like you found people who know more about polytopes, so that may actually be better!

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen - thanks so much for taking the time to respond, Jyrki. But "No !!!!" to your comment about whether the polytope folks will suffice. The polytope folks are essential because they help me (and any other interested parties) visualize certain symmetries of the roots and subsets of roots.  But in order to fully understand  my "linear" realization of the root-system of $E_8$ (assuming my tuples DO in fact realize this root-system), your insights and experience will, in my opinion, be absolutely crucial.  So thanks so much for your patience and willingness to help here.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen - also, if you haven't yet taken a look at my "bounty" question, I'd be grateful if you'd at least take a look: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2578813/is-there-an-internally-consistent-nearest-neighbor-relation-in-this-complete-lin  Even if you aren't interested, you might be able to suggest some profitable approaches to someone who is looking at the problem for me (off-line) - if the question has an affirmative answer, then I think this guy might be able to find it (he dropped out of an MIT math major because the courses were too easy for him . . .!)

Comment: I think that your *alphabet* has nine letters, and the strings have length two. Normally the *length* of a string tells the number of letters in it. So a string of length nine would be something like $123456789$ or $144255366$. I was a bit confused by your choice of words for a while :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen - no - as I said - "over ANY alphabet A", which means that the number of letters in the alphabet is irrelevant and immaterial.  I am using the numbers 12345679 to denote an ordered n-tuple of 9 letters over A, i.e. the length of the word over A is 9. It probably would have been clearer if I had said abcdefghi instead of 123456789, in which case this (12,23) would be this (ab,bc).  (continued next comment)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen - In any event, this question has been subsumed into this one https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2578813/is-there-an-internally-consistent-nearest-neighbor-relation-in-this-complete-lin , and it would be best if you make any future comments in THAT question - this is where Wendy Krieger is working also . . .

Comment: It seems to me that this set of 112 looks quite a bit like the root system $D_8$. If we associate the pair $(12)$ with the basis vector $e_1$, the pair with $(23)$ with $e_2$ et cetera up to $(89)$ and $e_8$, then it stands to reason that we might be able to think of $(21)$ as $-e_1$ and so on. Well, the vectors $e_i-e_j, 1\le i,j\le8, i\neq j$, are the 112 vectors of $D_8$.

Comment: I need to recall whether $D_8$ is a subsystem of $E_8$. Ok, I will move over to the other thread.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen - see Wendy Krieger's decomposition of $E_8$ in this thread https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2586698/what-is-the-complete-decomposition-of-e-8-roots-in-terms-of-the-objects-a-0

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen - I will now move over to the other thread also . . .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 240 vertices break into 128 verticies of a half-8-cube, and 112 vertices of the truncated 8-orthotope.

If you extend the packing of the 112 alone, you end up with the 8d semi-cubic, that is, the sets of 8 integers with even sum.

The Hamming-Code is simply the vertices of E8 in terms of the ordinary 8-cubic.  You take some code like 0F, and this expands to (0,0,0,0,½,½,½,½).  You then replicate this bit sequence for all sixteen coordinates, and you get a cube-cell with 16 vertices of the E8.  The Leech-code does the same thing with the Leech-lattice in 24 dimensions.

I found out something very interesting about the Hamming-code: It can be constructed from the representation of E8 as D4D4 * 4.  But because D4D4 can be constructed in six different ways, there is no dependency of the second nibble on the first, even if you suppose 0000 0000 and 1111 1111 is part of the code.  Without this, there are 24 different Hamming-codes on this construction.

The 112 roots given here belong to an inscribed B8. In order to reach E8, you need to get an even-number of -1 in all positions.

They represent the eutactic star of B8.  Two points are close neighbours, if they share one coordinate of the same sign and position, eg (2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0) and (2,0,0,0,0,-2,0,0) are adjacent.

My understanding of your scheme is to suppose the nine numbers sit like this:

```
 1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   +
 9    8    7    6    5    4    3    2    1   -
  +1    +1   0     0    0    0    0    0      (1,2)(2,3)   F   N
  +1    -1   0     0    0    0    0    0      (2,3)(1,2)   F   R
  -1    +1   0     0    0    0    0    0      (9,8)(8,7)   B   N
  -1    -1   0     0    0    0    0    0      (8,9)(7,8)   B   R
```

This is a trace of the petrie polygon of B8, excluding one of the eight edges.  I'm pretty sure that Coxeter has something to say on this, but i would have to look up that book.  I think the PP for B8 is 14.  This is then in some sort of right product with a group of 8 to give 112.

But i will have to play around with it tomorrow.

Comment: @WendyKrieger - thank you very much.  That is a very helpful "encapsulated visualization".  I am wondering if you can see a way to apply it in order to answer the follow-up question posed here:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2578813/is-there-an-internally-consistent-nearest-neighbor-relation-in-this-complete-lin

Comment: I don't really understand the question.  I just visualise these things.

Comment: @wendykrieger - and you do that wondrously well !!!

Comment: @DavidHalitsky  Updated the answer with many things that i see here.

Comment: @WendyKrieger - yes - your understanding of the scheme is exactly correct.  But I'm not sure I understand your comment about the even number of -1's required to get $E_8$.  These would NOT be part of the group's root-system, correct?  Also, you should really be looking at the situation in terms of my follow-on question, of which this question is Part I.  See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2578813/is-there-an-internally-consistent-nearest-neighbor-relation-in-this-complete-lin  This second post gives the representation of the 128 as well as the 112.

Comment: @WendyKrieger - thanks also very much for this particular comment "Two points are close neighbours, if they share one coordinate of the same sign and position, eg (2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0) and (2,0,0,0,0,-2,0,0) "  Very very helpful.

Comment: There's a lot to take in.  I'm doing this live.  I'll need to find time to sift through these posts tomorrow.

Comment: The rest of the relations here is that they are second neighbours, if they share no coordinate, or one opposite sign, eg (2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0) is at right angles to (2,-2,0,0,0,0,0,0) and to (0,0,2,0,0,0,2,0,0). 
The third-order is if they share a coordinate, with opposite sign, (-2,0,2,0,0,0,0,0), and opposite if both signs are reversed.

Comment: @wendykrieger - however much time you are willing an able to spend, I am very grateful.  Take your time please, because I have some remaining data reduction to do on the empirical side, and the results of this data reduction may be helpfulto you in deciding what we might and might not have both geometrically and group-theoretically.  Also, of course, we need the answer from the "cryptographers" to my "bounty" question - that is critical.

Comment: @wendykrieger - thanks for your additional definitions of 2nd and 3rd nearest-neighbors - I have added all three to the follow-on post about the complete linearization of the 128 as well as the 112.